# Python sorting part of a list

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, sorting

This code for finding the next permutation of a list of integers doesn't give the correct answer when I am using the sort function to sort the end of the list. But if I use sorted function it gives me the correct answer. Why is that happening? Please someone help me out with this one.

```
def nextPermutation(self, A):
    n = len(A)
    if n == 1:
        return A
    i = n - 2
    m = A[n - 1]
    while i >= 0:
        if A[i] < m:
            j = i + 1
            while j < len(A) and A[i] < A[j]:
                j += 1
            A[i], A[j - 1] = A[j - 1], A[i]
            A[i + 1 :].sort()  #Here if I use sorted it gives the correct answer
            return A
        else:
            m = max(A[i], m)
        i -= 1
    A.sort()
    return A
```

Comment: You take a slice, sort it and throw it away.

Comment: Try deleting/commenting out that line altogether.  That should have the same result as sorted(A[i+1:]) since that creates a copy that you're never using

Comment: What did your line look like that used `sorted()`?

Comment: @jsfan Perhaps `A[i + 1:] = sorted(A[i + 1:])`? I don't know if it makes sense in the algorithm, but at least it has a chance of doing something useful. :)

Comment: @jsfan  A[i + 1 : ] = sorted(A[i + 1:])

Answer (score 0):

Slicing creates a copy of the list.  When you say `A[i + 1:].sort()` you are creating a copy of some of `A`'s contents, and then sorting them.  It does not effect `A`.  Try this:

```
B = A[i + 1:]
B.sort()
return B
```

Of course, it would be easier to use `sorted()` and just `return sorted(A[i + 1:])`, but from your question I think for some reason you aren't interested in that.

Comment: The OP needs to mutate `A`; the design moves the `list` forward one permutation, so not partially ordering `A` means it doesn't work right.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in the line `A[i+1:].sort()`, the `A[i+1:]` part creates a *new* list object. Then, the `.sort()` part sorts that list in place. Then, this *new* object is thrown away without being assigned to anything. As a result, the line has no impact on your code.

I'm not sure why you're going through all this trouble, but it would be easier to write the class as:

```
from itertools import permutations

class PermutationList:
    def __init__(self, pool):
        self.pool = pool
        self._generator = permutations(self.pool)

    def __iter__(self):
        while True:
            try:
                yield list(next(self._generator))
            except StopIteration:
                self._generator = permutations(self.pool)
                raise StopIteration

test_list = PermutationList([1,2,3,4])

for perm in test_list:
    print perm

# Output
# [1, 2, 3, 4]
# [1, 2, 4, 3]
# [1, 3, 2, 4]
# ...
# [4, 3, 2, 1]
```

Comment: Why even bother with a special class? `for perm in map(list, permutations([1,2,3,4])):`. Done. If you don't need `list` results, you can just take the `tuple`s as `itertools.permutations` returns them without `map(list, ...)` wrapping. The class is just adding a ton of pointless overhead.

Comment: @ShadowRanger From the original post, the method has self as an argument, so I gave an example inside a class. It is a bunch of overhead for this simple example, but it was written under the assumption that the overhead exists regardless.

Comment: @ShadowRanger I guess the second point, which aids your argument, is that a class probably isn't necessary to begin with.

Comment: @o_o the question mentioned that I couldn't use    permutation() function or I else there would be penalty